# Passing a session Cookie in Request for getting data from API

Tags: saml-2.0, mod-auth

I am currently developing a web application that has separate API and Front end.

For production purpose, I wish to develop the web app locally while hosting the API on the remote server.

The issue is the API is behind a [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) authentication along with [Mod Auth](http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/) in second stage.

Using postman and wget I am able to access the API endpoint by adding a auth_tkt cookie in the request.However I am unable to access the same using AJAX.

I need help in executing the same.

Comment: if this question is really about mod_auth_tkt you should remove the mod-auth-openidc label

Comment: Updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help anyone else facing similar problem. The solution to this problem is using chromium with disabled security. It sends your session cookies along with the request. Also there is no problem of CORS that was coming in picture before.